# Quarkus 3: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne

Tags: hibernate, quarkus

We are currently migrating a suite of different quarkus applications from v2 to v3. We are currently facing issues when we have entity-relationships as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Library {

    @Id
    Long id;
    
    String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "libraryId")
    List<Book> books;

}
```

Which is mapped to:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    Long id;

    Long libraryId;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "library_id")
    Library library;

}
```

Upon starting quarkus on version 3.1.1.FINAL, we get the below error

```
2023-06-12 10:09:05,666 ERROR [io.qua.run.boo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @ef9296d)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.BinderHelper.checkMappedByType(BinderHelper.java:1086)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.isReversePropertyInJoin(CollectionBinder.java:1571)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.noAssociationTable(CollectionBinder.java:1582)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1543)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1534)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1857)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1814)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:328)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootMetadataBuilder.build(FastBootMetadataBuilder.java:406)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.createMetadata(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.constructMetadataAdvance(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.initializeJpa(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:40)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder$1.created(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:78)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initBeanContainer(ArcRecorder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

I've included a simple reproducer project, which can be found here:
https://github.com/hreem-it/Quarkus-v3-hibernate-reproducer

The project also includes a file called tree.txt, containing a dependency-tree extract for the whole project.

Would appreciate any and all help I can get.

Regards

Comment: There is an error in `mappedBy`: you should use other side property name, not column name so `mappedBy="library"`.
Also mapping both `library` and `libraryId` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `OneToMany` should say by which table it is mapped

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "library")
    List<Book> books;
```

2. `JoinColumns` should specify by which column in a table should it reference the `library`

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "libraryId")
private Library library;
```

3. You cannot have a field that is used for `@ManyToOne` as a column in a entity, so next line should be removed.

```java
//    should be removed
//    Long libraryId;
```